# NSMutableParagraphStyle is not called

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I have a UILabel on xib file and I want to increase the line spacing of the texts.

I tried to write, but with the code below only text alignment is called and line spacing remains the same.  Why  "paragraphStyle.lineSpacing" is not called?

```
 class PlaySheetCellLeft: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet var LBLTitle:UILabel!


    var message:[String:Any]? {
            didSet{
                guard let msg = self.message else { return  }
                self.LBLTitle.text = title
            }

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 10
            let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString()
            attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
            LBLTitle.attributedText = attrString
            LBLTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

        }
}
```

Comment: Your program has 4 `{` and 6 `}`, and the indentation is very misleading.  Is this actually what your class looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a range with an empty attributed string, so the style isn't being set on anything.

When you create your range, you're actually creating a range like this: `NSMakeRange(0, 0)`.

You should pass your string into the creation of the mutable attributed string like this: `NSMutableAttributedString(string: "your string")`

You'll also need to set this when you set the text of your label, which by the looks of your code isn't in `awakeFromNib`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using plist file to edit attributed string. Therefore when I pass string all labels will be the same letter. Any solution for the problem?

Comment: Yes, as I said, set the attributed string wherever you set the text from the plist file.